# Cannot set default text for @Html.TextAreaFor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am not able to set default text for `@HTML.TextAreaFor`

This is all I tried, but didn't work, it always shows empty text area

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmployeeDescription, new {  @Text = ViewBag.Model.EmployeeDescription })

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmployeeDescription, new {  @text = ViewBag.Model.EmployeeDescription })

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmployeeDescription, new {  @Value = ViewBag.Model.EmployeeDescription })

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmployeeDescription, new {  @value = ViewBag.Model.EmployeeDescription })
```

Exactly same thing is working for `@Html.TextBoxFor` with `@Value` but not with `TextArea` :(

Can anybody help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I was doing a silly mistake

Now I replaced my Index method from this

```
    public ActionResult Index(Guid empId)
    {
        ViewBag.Model = new EditEmployeePopulator(session, empId).GetModel();
        return View();
    }
```

To this

```
    public ActionResult Index(Guid empId)
    {
        return View(new EditEmpoyeePopulator(session, empId).GetModel());
    }
```

And it worked!

I was doing that in the wrong way earlier. I was assigning my model as a property of ViewBag and was accessing it through ViewBag only in my view and that was my mistake.

When I replaced my code it started working with this only

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmployeeDescription)
```

:) :)

Thanks for all the replies

Answer (score 3):

You should be setting the text on the model before you pass it to the view.  This is true for the TextBoxFor as well.  You should not have to set the value using HTML attributes.  Note that a textarea doesn't have text or value attributes, it's value, when initially rendered, is the HTML between the opening and closing tags.

Comment: Yes the model has the value because my screen is edit screen, so model already has all the values filled
So m.EmployeeDescription is filled with the value before using but still not working

Comment: What does it do if you just omit the HTML attribute entirely.

Comment: You mean if I completely remove '@Value' or '@Text' part?
Something like this 
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.EmployeeDescription)

Then also it doesn't work, the text area still remains empty

Comment: What is odd to me is that you are referencing a "Model" on the ViewBag.  What does your controller code look like where you are returning the view?  I wonder if you are actually setting the model on the view or just in the ViewBag.

Comment: This is the line I am using in my view

@model SST.ViewModel.EmployeeManagerDetails.EditEmployee

and this is my controller's index action

   public ActionResult Index(Guid empId)
        {
            ViewBag.Model = new EditEmployeePopulator(session,empId).GetModel();

            return View();
        }

Comment: Hey!! just solved the problem by just replacing this

return View();  ->   return View([My Model Object]);

Thanks!! for pointing out, you helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this by natural of the TextArea element of the HTML itself because if you see the view source you will find the value or the text but for the HTML this not has affect on the TextArea, so to add a default value you need to put text inside the TextArea tag itself

so you can just initialize the object in the creating with your default value as the following:

```
Employee e = new Employee { Id = 1, EmployeeDescription = "Default Value" };
```